# How to save new customer attribute value from admin new tab?

Tags: customer, custom-attributes, tabs, magento2.3.3

I am using Magento 2.3.3 version. I just installed Magento. I have created a custom attribute for a customer in the admin side.

**Issue:** I set new customer attribute textbox in custom tab but its not saving while click save customer button

**1)Here is a picture.**
[image: magento custom customer attribute]

**2)Here is a code of new attribute**

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Magento Username',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

And Below code used from this website https://webkul.com/blog/tab-with-form-in-admin-customer-edit-magento-2/

**Issue:**
so this new attribute textbox show in demo tab  and when I click save customer button it does not post custom textbox value from demo tab
**Here is code:** `Packagename\CustomerAttribute\view\adminhtml\layout\customer_index_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
             <block class="Sashas\CustomerAttribute\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tabs" name="custom_edit_tab_view" />
        </referenceBlock>    
    </body>
</page>
```

**Here is image:** 
[image: custom tab]

**Here is code:**

```
namespace Packagename\CustomerAttribute\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit; 
    use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
    /**
     * Customer account form block
     */
    class Tabs extends Generic implements TabInterface
    {
         /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
         */
         protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
        protected $_systemStore;
        /**
         * Core registry
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         */
        protected $_coreRegistry;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
            $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
            parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        }

        /**
         * @return string|null
         */
        public function getCustomerId()
        {
            return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
        }
        public function getCustomer()
        {   
            return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($this->getCustomerId());
        }

        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return __('Demo Tab');
        }

        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return __('Demo Tab');
        }

        /**
         * @return bool
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * @return bool
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
           if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Tab class getter
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabClass()
        {
            return '';
        }

        /**
         * Return URL link to Tab content
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabUrl()
        {
            return '';
        }

        /**
         * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function isAjaxLoaded()
        {
            return false;
        }
        public function initForm()
        {
            if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
                return $this;
            }
            /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
            $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
            $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('myform_');
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();
    $customer = $customerFactory->load($this->getCustomerId());
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Fields Information')]);

                $fieldset->addField(
                    'demo_field',
                    'text',
                    [
                        'name' => 'customer[magento_username]',//customer[magento_username]
                        'data-form-part' => $this->getData('customer_form'),
                        'label' => __('Magento username'),
                        'title' => __('Magento username'),
                        'value' => $customer->getMagentoUsername(),
                    ]
                );
            $this->setForm($form);
            return $this;
        }
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        protected function _toHtml()
        {
            if ($this->canShowTab()) {
                $this->initForm();
                return parent::_toHtml();
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
        /**
         * Prepare the layout.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
    // You can call other Block also by using this function if you want to add phtml file.
      /*  public function getFormHtml() 
        {
            $html = parent::getFormHtml();
            $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Packagename\CustomerAttribute\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\EdditionalBlock'
            )->toHtml();
            return $html;
        } */
    }
```

Comment: Use `$customer = $customerFactory->create()->load($this->getCustomerId());` in `Tabs.php`.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh you are not getting my point bro,if I write in textbox which I created in new custom tab,and when I  click save customer it should save the value in new customer attribute's value

Comment: @NirajPatel did you find a solution for this?!

Comment: @SantiBM Can I give extension ? so that module has same functionality so you will have an idea to solve your problem

Comment: Yes pleas! that would be great

Comment: @SantiBM create chatroom on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ and invite me I will share and discuss there

Comment: @NirajPatel can you please join https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119545/how-to-save-new-customer-attribute-value-from-admin-new-tab